# Communicating with QProcess from a QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qprocess

Structure Of Application:

MainWindow -> ProcessingThread(QThread) - > QProcess for Python Script

In the Run/Exec loop of Processing Thread I would like to interact with the process.

How do I go about it?

Current Problem:
I know both `ProcessingThread(QThread)` and its Run loop run inside different threads. Hence if I initialize the `QProcess` in `QThread` constructor I am unable to interact with the process because of following error:

> QSocketNotifier: Socket Notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from
>   another thread

and if I try to initialize the process in the Run Loop I get the following error:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different
>   thread
>       (Parent is ProcessingThread(0x984b2a0), parent's thread is QThread(0x940e180)), 
>       current thread is ProcessingThread(0x984b2a0)

If I initialize the `QProcess` in `ProcessingThread` constructor, I am able to interact with the script perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Update: Also The reason for using `QThread` is because I am performing image processing, the Processing Threads keeps fetching images from camera. Some of these images need to be further processed by the Python script running in `QProcess`.

Update 2: CODE

```
void MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
    ...
    debugProcessingThread = new DebugProcessingThread();
}

class DebugProcessingThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
    private:
    qProcess *myprocess;
}

DebugProcessingThread::DebugProcessingThread()
{
    ...
    myProcess = new QProcess(this);
    myProcess->start("python abc.py");
    connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(processStarted()));
    connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(processError()));
     connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readStandardOutput()));

    myProcess->waitForStarted();
}

void DebugProcessingThread::processError()
{
    qDebug("PROCESS ERROR");
    qDebug() << myProcess->errorString();
}

void DebugProcessingThread::readStandardOutput()
{
    qDebug("READ DATA");
    qDebug(myProcess->readAll().toStdString().c_str());
    myProcess->write("out.txt\n");
}

void DebugProcessingThread::processStarted()
{
    qDebug("Process has started");
}
```

The above code works perfectly.

But I want to send and receive data from function:

```
void DebugProcessingThread::run()
{
     myProcess->write("out.txt\n");
     // This Throws socket Error
}
```

Comment: Is it related to c++ or python?

Comment: The script executed is Python, the QT Program is C++

Comment: If you create objects in the `run` method, you cannot set `this` as the parent. Maybe a [worker object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) would work for you better?

Comment: I dont understand how a worker object would make it better? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Because when you move the object to a new thread, it moves all of its children to a new thread as well. If you subclass `QThread`, the instance of that class will live in the main thread (or in the thread where you create that instance), while everything you do in the `run` method will be in the new thread. By creating a worker object and calling `moveToThread` you won't have that problem (unless you call its functions directly from the main thread).

Comment: I do not exactly know what your issue might be, but have you tried moveToThread() of some of your objects? And also maybe you do not need to set the parent for the object you want to have in another thread. And if you want to keep ownership of a 'child' (living in another thread) don't do it in Qt-ish way (i.e. child-parent relation) but with a normal pointer inside another object.

Comment: By the way you first say *if I initialize the QProcess in QThread constructor I am unable to interact with the process*, and then you say *If I initialize the QProcess in ProcessingThread constructor, I am able to interact with the script perfectly.*. So which is it?

Comment: @thuga Have attached some code to make it clear. please check thank you.

Comment: @V.K. Have attached some code to make it clear, please check thank you.

Comment: It definitely looks like you should just go with the worker object method. Right now as you noticed, you are mixing two threads.

Comment: I suggest reading [this article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/)

Comment: Note that documentation for [QThread::run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run) states: *You can reimplement this function to facilitate advanced thread management.* QThread is not the thread, but more like a thread controller, so you have no need to inherit from QThread, unless you want to change how the thread management works.

Answer (score 1):

Keep long story short, you shouldn't instantiate anything you going to use in your new thread in the constructor, as every object instantiated there will get an affinity of the thread *where* your QThread object is created, common practice is either not to subclass QThread at all, just use QObject and moveToThread, and then connect some slot like init() to QThread started() signal, so you can do all initialisation inside the init() which will run inside a new thread, or if for whatever reasons you need QThread subclassing instantiate everything in run().

Also pay attention that QThread itself is nothing more nothing less then a *wrapper* of your real thread and stays as an object in a thread where you created it.